# Is any cross-fertilization occurring between the disciplines of game semantics and set theory?

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory

I've recently been introduced (at a superficial 'wiki' level) to the [Axiom of determinacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy) and [Descriptive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory).

While looking up [Witness_(mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness_(mathematics)), I found the link to [Game semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_semantics).

> Are researchers in these two disciplines, set theory and game
>   semantics, able to 'jam together'?

Please excuse the vagueness of this soft question. But what can you expect from a wiki-dabbler?

Just hoping it can generate some interesting comments/answers so I can learn something...

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-games/ (and [jelly not jam](http://www.math.ac.vn/publications/vjm/VJM_23/No.%202/M.%20Scheepers.PDF))

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is definitely a lot of interaction here. Once we move beyond first-order logic, semantics *in general* becomes very set-theoretic. So while studying game semantics for *weak* systems need not involve set theory, beyond a certain point we're arguably *part of* set theory. Vaanaanen's paper ["Games and Trees in Infinitary Logic: A Survey"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-017-0522-6_5) might be a good place to start; the epic volume ["Model-theoretic logics"](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235417263) edited by Barwise and Feferman also has a great deal of information on the topic (and really everything else relating to logics beyond first-order), especially the chapter on [game quantification](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pl/1235417276) (noting in passing that AD itself is essentially just De Morgan's law for the game quantifier, for countable structures).